TextColor Android Studio Kotlin
Good day all.
new to Android, and I have small app that is working.
I would like to show one portion of the text in a different color.
Here is my function.
//show Medications
fun getAllMeds(): List<Medication> {
    val medList = mutableListOf<Medication>()
    val db = readableDatabase
    val query = "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME"
    val cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null)

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        val id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_ID))
        val medname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_MEDNAME))
        val medpill = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_MEDPILL))
        val medtaken = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_MEDTAKEN))

        var text = "Take <font color=Red>("  + medpill + ")</font> pill every "

        val med = Medication(id, medname, text, medtaken)

        medList.add(med)
    }
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    return medList
}

the portion under text does not change color, just prints the whole line.
if have this appear on main screen in a TextView.
any pointers would be appreciated.
Have a great day!

In your activity or fragment, when you set the TextView content, use the Html.fromHtml method.
textView.text = Html.fromHtml(med.text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)

If your app supports devices running on API levels below 24, use the deprecated Html.fromHtml method for backward compatibility:
textView.text = Html.fromHtml(med.text)


To style text with color in Android, you can use buildSpannedString along with ColorSpan. This is an official Android method for modifying strings.
For a detailed guide, refer to this Medium article: Spannable String: Text Styling with Spans.
Update:
/**
 * Meds data class to hold the medication details.
 * */
data class Medication(
    val id: Int,
    val medname: String,
    val medpill: SpannedString,
    val medtaken: String
)

/**
 * Function to get all the medications from the database.
 * */
fun getAllMeds(): List<Medication> {
    val medList = mutableListOf<Medication>()
    val db = readableDatabase
    val query = "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME"
    val cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null)

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        val id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_ID))
        val medname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_MEDNAME))
        val medpill = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_MEDPILL))
        val medtaken = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_MEDTAKEN))

        val medpillSpanned = buildSpannedString {
            append("Take ")
            append(medpill)
            append(" pill every ")
            setColor(Color.RED, medpill)
        }

        val med = Medication(id, medname, medpillSpanned, medtaken)

        medList.add(med)
    }
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    return medList
}

/**
 * Helper function to set the color of a specific value in a [SpannableStringBuilder].
 * */
fun SpannableStringBuilder.setColor(
    color: Int,
    value: String?
) {
    val start = value?.let { indexOf(value) } ?: 0
    val end = start + (value?.length ?: 0)
    setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(color),
        start, end, SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
}


appreciate the 2 responses.  unfortunately, I tried both suggestions and they will not work.  My string is from the database, and therefore the textbox is not available.  will continue the search.  appreciate the samples, as they do work if I have access to a TextView etc. directly

But this will work brother, your database is having String right? But in your data class you can have a field as val string: SpannedString because as we see you are creating a model called Med(.., .., .., ..) so you can have a SpannedString in it, and then just set that text to the TextView, it should work.

Check the updated answer brother

After reviewing answer form Meet Miyani, it looks like I will need more study on this.  For some reason, i am not able to get it to work.  if I use answer above, it cause 20 errors elsewhere where "val medpill: SpannedString," is a string not SpannedString.  As stated, new to Android.  First attempt (after many hours of self taught).  Appreciate the help.

I see, in that case you use Spanned string only at the place where you are setting the text in the TextView, because you already have the necessary data in the model.
